# Backbone collection missed few models while adding models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am new to backbone; i am also using marionette. but this case is related to backbone collection. Issue is while page loading; it only adds one models while rest are missed.

For more info see the image; 
[image]

- in editor part; left side; blue circle mark is where issue is created
  in console;
- right side red Circle mark; 1st one printed while loading
  the page; and 2nd one i have created myself; for that i have copied
  the "temp_ll" to some global variable so that it can come in the
  console.
- and this is marked in green square; see both are same

when i add models to the collection in console; it adds all three models; while missed two models while loading the page.
is this related to my programming mistake?? or else???

i am using Jquery 1.9.1, underscore 1.4.4, backbone 1.0.0, marionette v1.0.3

Sample data :

```
   {
    "axislist": [
        "None"
    ],
    "axisdata": [
        {
            "memberlist": [
                "None"
            ],
            "mydata": [
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q2 2008",
                        "10,339,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q2 2009",
                        "6,076,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q3 2009",
                        "8,823,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q4 2009",
                        "9,422,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q1 2010",
                        "8,155,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q2 2010",
                        "5,505,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q3 2010",
                        "8,161,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q4 2010",
                        "4,023,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q1 2011",
                        "7,021,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q2 2011",
                        "9,610,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q3 2011",
                        "12,881,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q4 2011",
                        "10,610,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q1 2012",
                        "6,388,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q2 2012",
                        "6,938,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q3 2012",
                        "5,036,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q4 2012",
                        "6,017,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q1 2013",
                        "5,240,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q2 2013",
                        "3,804,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q3 2013",
                        "4,023,000,000"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Ddata": [
                        "Q4 2013",
                        "10,059,000,000"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "header": [
                "Period",
                "Balance as of"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

above is the actual value of the first element of `ill/temp_ll` array. while other elements are 5-10 times of this data.

as suggested by the comment; i have added `id` attribute to model; but it didn't work.
its screenshot is below.
[image]

Comment: What specifically is in the model data? Text would be better than a screenshot. Can you reproduce the problem at jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: @muistooshort: updated in the post...

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like an `id` attribute in your data. What happens if you include `id`s in the model data to uniquely identify each model's chunk of data?

Comment: @muistooshort: it didn't work. see the updated post.

Comment: I think you're missing a `parse()` step in your collection. it looks like the models it's creating are from the `axisdata` and `axislist` objects instead of what you intend, from the `mydata` object?